# how to run cucumber test using command line

Tags: cucumber

I have test cases written in cucumber with java. I am using IDE IntelliJ. I can run from IDE UI by simply right click a feature file. but now the requirement is I need to run tests in jenkins using command line.

explore maven option but has another issue with authentication.

is there any other way to directly run cucumber features through command line?

Comment: Hey ! Did you manage to run the test from command line? i have the same requirement please. The website provided in the below answer is not working

Answer (score 0):

See the JUnit section here: https://cukes.info/running.html

Create the empty class as described and then run the empty class as a junit with something like this:

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore RunCukesTest
```