# Running cucumber-jvm in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

After some research into running Cucumber on Jenkins I have come to a dead end, I have read some post here about Running Cucumber but most are error not the process.

[Running via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003830/how-to-run-cucumber-test-using-command-line) the problem here is that I don't know how to call this in Jenkins after building.

I have Jenkins running on an Ubuntu server. Everything for building a maven project is setup, but how would one run the Runcukes file or setup the pom file in a way to call cucumber to start running?

Answer (score 4):

Wire up a Maven task to run cucumber.  As cucumber generates stubs for junit, maven's surefire plugin will run the tests nicely.

Jenkins has full support for running maven builds, so you won't have any issues there.

Comment: i got it working however it now also runs cucumber while using clean install this makes for a lot of failures as there are some steps using Selenium WebDriver

Comment: glad to hear you got it working, but it sounds like you have integration tests in your unit testing section of your build.  Just because it is called "junit" doesn't mean you are constrained to writing only unit tests with it.  Might want to move some of those tests into the validation layer, and possibly work in maven driven Selenium test plugins too.